# How do I redirect standard output messages to FLTK's Fl_Multiline_Output?

Tags: c++, fltk

```
Fl_Multiline_Output* m_pLogOutput;

m_pLogOutput = new Fl_Multiline_Output(20, 330, 570, 530, "Log Output:");
m_pLogOutput->align(FL_ALIGN_TOP_LEFT);
```

I want to redirect any message printed to standard output (like std::cout << "Hello world") to appear on this m_pLogOutput. Is that possible?

Comment: There are several ways of doing this.  The problem with Fl_Multiline_Output is it does not have an append method.  You need to accumulate the strings and set the value whenever an endl is output.  The problem with this is that it always scrolls back to line 1.  This no obvious until the text starts scrolling.

Comment: @cup Thanks for replying! How do you implement the "set the value whenever an endl is output." part?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this - this example uses TextDisplay instead of MultiLineOutput.  TextDisplay has scrollbars: MultilineOutput does not.  This is written in FLTK2, calls are similar to FLTK1 without the FL_ and underscores between words.

It defines a class called ConOut.  Note that you must not

```
#include <iostream>
```

since cout is redefined.

```
#include <fltk/run.h>
#include <fltk/ValueInput.h> // necessary for bug in mingw32?
#include <fltk/Window.h>
#include <fltk/Button.h>
#include <fltk/TextDisplay.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace fltk;

class ConOut: public std::ostringstream
{
public:
    ConOut& operator << (std::ostream&(*f)(std::ostream&))
    {
        if (f == std::endl)
        {
            *this << "\n";
            std::string cumulative = control->text() + str();
            control->text(cumulative.c_str());
            str("");
        }
        else
        {
            // Don't worry about the warning
            *this << f;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    void SetWidget(TextDisplay* in_control)
    {
        control = in_control;
    }

    TextDisplay* control;

    template <typename T>
    inline ConOut& operator << (const T& t)
    {
        (*(std::ostringstream*) this) << t;
        return *this;
    }
};

ConOut cout;

void cb_cauli(Widget*, void*)
{
    cout << "Cauliflower" << std::endl;
}

void cb_brocolli(Widget*, void*)
{
    cout << "Brocolli" << std::endl;
}

void cb_cabbage(Widget*, void*)
{
    cout << "Cabbage" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int btnw = 100, btnh = 30, bdr = 10;
    int dlgw = bdr * 4 + 3 * btnw, dlgh = 200 + btnh + 3 * bdr, x, y, w, h;
    Window * window = new Window(dlgw, dlgh);
    window->begin();

    // Create the multiline output
    x = bdr;
    y = bdr;
    w = dlgw - 2 * bdr;
    h = 200;
    TextDisplay* text2 = new TextDisplay(x, y, w, h,"");
    text2->clear_flag(fltk::ALIGN_MASK);
    text2->set_flag(fltk::ALIGN_BOTTOM);
    window->resizable(text2);

    // Create the buttons which use cout
    y += h + bdr;
    w = btnw; h = btnh;
    Button* cauli = new Button(x, y, w, h, "Cauliflower");
    cauli->callback(cb_cauli);
    x += w + bdr;
    Button* brocolli = new Button(x, y, w, h, "Brocolli");
    brocolli->callback(cb_brocolli);
    x += w + bdr;
    Button* cabbage = new Button(x, y, w, h, "Cabbage");
    cabbage->callback(cb_cabbage);

    // Set the widget for cout
    cout.SetWidget(text2);

    window->end();
    window->show(argc,argv);
    return fltk::run();
}
```